# How to build an RNN network to mirror the input timeseries to the output layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to build a recurrent neural network (RNN) autoencoder, specifically using SimpleRNN and LSTMs, that shall mirror the input timeseries to the output layer. I have timeseries consisting of n_samples of several variables (n_features) (n_samples x n_features) array.
The topology of autoencoder shall be: **n_features >>> n_features/2 >>> n_features**

I firstly divided the data to training and testing data sets (first 80% is for training and the rest for testing and validation).
Then created TimeseriesGenerator object to be used for fitting the model:

```
n_lag = 10 # number of lag in time steps
batch_size = 1 # number of timeseries samples in each batch
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_x_train, scaled_x_train,
                                length=n_lag, batch_size=batch_size)
validation_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_x_train, scaled_x_train, 
                                           length=n_lag, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Then I created the model as follows:

```
encoder = Sequential()
encoder.add(LSTM(4, activation = 'tanh', input_shape = (n_lag, n_features), return_sequences = False))
encoder.add(RepeatVector(int(n_features/2)))

decoder = Sequential()
decoder.add(LSTM(4, activation = 'tanh', return_sequences=True))
decoder.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_features)))

autoencoder = Sequential([encoder, decoder])

autoencoder.fit(generator, epochs=3, validation_data = validation_generator)
```

But the model doesn't behave as expected as I fear that the problem is in the dimensions of the input and output data and their relation to the n_units in SimpleRNN and LSTM layers.

Can I get any help regarding how to build such autoencoders with multi-input/multi-output timeseries?